# SQL difficult statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Currently I'm looking for a solution. English is not my native language so I added two pictures to clarify it a bit. My knowledge of SQL is rather basic.

[image: Table]
[image: Database]

A chair (end-product) contains several components.
 Each component contains an item number, each spare set contains multiple item numbers.
 In the database a spare set is in the same table as an end-product.
 The chairs and spare parts are categorized in different groups.

Is it possible to create a table like that? If it's possible how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: School assignment? What have you tried?

Comment: Using one table might not be the best solve this. You will definitely need multiple tables which are related to each other.

Comment: @jarlh, it's for an internship. I can two different tables, just not able to combine the two.

Comment: @Fleuv, true, but it's en existing rather complex database so I can't change anything about that.

Comment: So is this about creating the tables so they can be joined in a query to get that pivot result? Or do the tables already exist, and you want to know how to get that pivot result?

Comment: If you want to do a general pivot (getting a column for every product, without knowing how many products there are) is not possible (and not advised, since you can end up with 10000 columns - who wants to read that?), otherwise check [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
Table: Products  -- a table of products
ProductID  ProductName  DateAdded
1          Chair X      01/01/2016
2          Chair Y      05/05/2016
3          Spare Set A  06/06/2016
...

Table: Components  -- a table of components
ComponentID  ComponentName  ItemNumber  DateAdded
1            Backrest       X01         01/01/2016
2            Headrest       X02         01/01/2016
...

Table: ProductComponent  -- a lookup/mapping table to link Product and Component
PCID  ComponentID  ProductID  DateAdded
1     1            1          01/01/2016
2     2            1          01/01/2016
...
```

DateAdded is the date the product or component was first entered into the database. It is for audit purposes.